# Inline assembly and registers

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I'm trying to use the inline assembler from GCC.
What I want is to read the result of a while loop.

For context, the code is written inside a C file with its own header file, externed and called from a C++ main that prints the output using std::cout.

Here is the current code:

```
int asmTest_LoopExample() {
    int result = 0;
    int i = 10;
    int j = 50;
    asm(
            "While:"
            "cmp %1, %2;"   // Compare result with j
            "jle End;"
            "add $1, %1;"
            "add $1, %0;"       // Increment result by 1
            "jmp While;"
            "End:"
            : "=a"(result)
            : "b"(i), "c"(j)
            );
    return result - i; // Return the count of iterations
}
```

This indeed return how many iterations the loop ran, but in order to do so I need to do result - i.

I attempted multiple ways to get the value in %0 to result, but nothing seems to work, can someone more versed in how the inline assembly works explain me why this is the case?

What I attempted: Move values from %1 and %2 to EAX and EBX and store result in ECX. Move values between those registers in multiple ways so I eventually move %0 to EAX, same issue.

I guess that there is something that I'm overlooking here, but I was not able to find the answer after like a full day of searching.

Comment: You specified `result` as output only as such your `result = 0;` has no effect. Use read-write operand.

Comment: I'm certainly no assembly expert, nor do I know anything (really) about GCC's inline `asm` syntax, but isn't there an *increment* instruction you can use instead of `add $1, %1;`? Something that I imagine would look like `inc %1;`.

Comment: Instead of `mov %0, eax`, try `mov $0, eax` before the loop. (Note, the latter is more commonly written `xor eax, eax`.)

Comment: @AdrianMole: That's correct.  When tuning for most CPUs, it's worth saving a byte of code size by using `inc %reg` instead of `add $1, %reg` (in AT&T syntax).  See [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36510095) - the details of when `inc` is worse on which CPUs are highly non-obvious.  (It leaves CF unmodified while writing other FLAGS.)

Comment: @prl: in AT&T syntax, that's `mov $0, %eax` or `xor %eax, %eax`.  (The `%` isn't part of the register name, so it's still correct to describe that as a `mov` to EAX, but reg names need to be decorated with `%` in AT&T syntax when you're writing out the actual instruction as code instead of talking about its operands in English.)

Comment: Two bugs here: what @Jester pointed out, that `"=a"(result)` tells the compiler EAX is a write-only output of the asm statement, so the old value of the variable doesn't need to get loaded into EAX before running the asm.  Use `"+&a"(result)`, an early-clobber (&) read+write output, since you still read other inputs after the first write.  And (2), you modify `"b"(i)`, which you promised the compiler was a read-only input.  So this function has undefined behaviour, and probably can even break its caller since EBX is a call-preserved register.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code:

```
int asmTest_LoopExample() {
    int result;
    int i = 10;
    int j = 50;
    asm(
            "mov %%EBX, %%EDX;"
            "While:"
            "cmp %%EDX, %%ECX;"   // Compare result with j
            "jle End;"
            "add $1, %%EDX;"
            "add $1, %%EAX;"
            "jmp While;"
            "End:"
            : "+&a"(result)
            : "b"(i), "c"(j)
            : "edx"
            );
    return result; // Return the count of iterations
}
```

Edit: I uploaded a fixed code, I use add in purpose for those 2 operations since what I aim is to learn more about the assembler.
Thx for all the feedback and the links in comments!

I decided to keep the use of EDX entirely for educational purposes, but using i as an output parameter is indeed better.

Comment: If you wrote the constraints properly to tell the compiler where the inputs and outputs are, you wouldn't need to start or end with `mov`.  (see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77239947/inline#comment136169268_77239947) under the question).  This happens to work in your case, but it still has bugs: you modify EBX, which you told the compiler was a read-only input.  You modify EDX which you didn't tell the compiler about at all.  e.g. `"edx"` in the clobber list.  It could break a function it inlined into, if the compiler was keeping a value in EDX across this asm statement.

Comment: Can you please @PeterCordes show me a fixed example of the code and comments on that, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info has links to multiple correct examples of getting variables in and out of inline asm statements.  [Why can't local variable be used in GNU C basic inline asm statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60227941) discusses how to think about inline asm statements, that the syntax is designed for describing a single instruction to the compiler.  [get string length in inline GNU Assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656087) has an example of code with inputs and outputs that are like loop counters.

Comment: For the original code in your question, you want `: "+&r"(result), "+&r"(i)` for outputs (both actually read+write operands), and `: "r"(j)` for pure inputs.  That makes it safe for `%0` and `%1` to be destination operands of `add`.  I used `"r"` for all of them because there's no benefit to forcing the compiler to pick a certain register for any of these.   You can look at the compiler-generated asm to see which regs it picked, e.g. using https://godbolt.org/.  ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)).

Comment: One SUB at the end is more efficient that incrementing two separate counters inside the loop, but the code in your question correctly uses `%number` operand references for the compiler to fill in.  If you want an extra temporary register, you can do `"=r"(dummy)` for an `int dummy` C variable.

Comment: Looks correct now, but without the flexibility of changing to `"r"` constraints to let the compiler pick registers like you had when you were using `%0` through `%2`.  You can attach names to operands like `[res] "+&r"(result)` and then use `%[res]` instead of `%0` in the template.